# Installed Magento 2.1 via composer. What's step 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, installation, composer

I just installed Magento 2.1 via Composer in my local XAMPP 5.6 server.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
cd magento2
composer update
```

The folder structure generated:

**htdocs/**

> magento2/update (folder with other files, folders and index.php) 
>   magento2/composer.json 
>   magento2/.gitignore

What exactly am I supposed to do next?

I tried to running `127.0.0.1/magento2` in the browser and it loads the directory structure. If I run `127.0.0.1/magento2/update`, it gives forbid access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct permissions and run `magento setup:install`

For more information see the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to run command,

**For upgrade,**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**For Deployment of store,**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**For Indexing**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

If cache is enable,

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Remove var folder and check frontend.

Comment: Also make sure you enabled [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite)